# typeahead - parsing a json array from a remote URL

Tags: javascript, typeahead

I'm trying to create an auto-suggest city with type-ahead and have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/m0ojmpqv/

However, when typing I don't seem to get any auto-suggestion.

Could anybody point me in the right direction? I'm a little lost with typeahead!

Thanks :-)

```
<input class="typeahead"></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is CORS the API your using doesn't allow send back data with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' hence the browser blocks it and type ahead swallows the problem.

I suggest finding a new API or using a json file.

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't think to check that. Thanks for pointing that out :-)